# Html tags shows as it is in page when formatted from c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, string-formatting

I am trying to format a string to add spaces in between the strings in c#.

```
summary.AppendFormat("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{0}&nbsp;{1}:&nbsp;{2}{3}</br> ", item.FirstName, item.LastName, item.Completed ? item.Summary : "not&nbsp;completed", item.Schedule == DateTime.MinValue ? "" : "&nbsp;(" + DateTime.ToShortDate(item.Schedule, user) + ")");
```

This should render in the HTML page as

First Round    Suri Narayanan: recommend (3/2/2012)

but i am seeing this as like below in html page

```
 First Round</br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Suri&nbsp;Narayanan:&nbsp;recommend &nbsp;(3/2/2012)</br>
```

if i edit the same using firebug, say if i put some space, then its getting formatted well and good.

Please let me know your comments on this.

Comment: what type of control is "summary"?

Comment: Sorry for that confusion. Its StringBuilder and then later doing a Response.Write(summary.ToString());

Comment: and how is it being added to your page?

Comment: How are you outputting the string to the page?

Comment: Response.Write(summary.ToString());

Comment: Are you also writing a Response header? It looks like you are sending the text as content-type:'text'.

Comment: I am not using Response Header.. i am using just Response.Write()

Answer (score 0):

You should use Literal like below.

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal" runat="server" Mode="PassThrough"></asp:Literal>
```

Literal.text = "Your text"

Comment: i cannot use literal.. this is something like, i am calling the same from the javascript to write dynamic fields. Is there any other way to fix this issue?